# Could I ask how to run a Ruby program in Atom?

Tags: support, scope

As you know, [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) is a powerful editor for coders, and it supports many languages.

I am new to Ruby and Atom, and I wrote a "hello world" program to print, but I do not know how to run it.

So, could I ask this type of question on Stack Overflow?

[image]

Comment: As you don't seem to know, your initial statement is incorrect, I have never heard of Atom, apart from being a computer by the company Acorn.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You *could*... I mean, it's the sort of question that'd be on-topic...

...But you should probably search first.

[image]

Note that one of the first results suggests this is a duplicate: [Running Ruby programs in Atom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172897/running-ruby-programs-in-atom)

...and it's *pretty similar* to this question also: [How to run a program in Atom Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799522/how-to-run-a-program-in-atom-editor)

...so if you read both of those, follow the instructions, and *still* can't get it to work, you can post a question about that (including copious details on what you tried to make it work and what appears to be going wrong) and you should be fine.